# Reflection in Swift

Tags: swift, methods, reflection

I would like to create a function (Function A) that have as a parameter a function (Function B) with multiple parameters.

So the function (B) can have 0,1 or more parameters and inside the function (A) I would like to do different things based on the number and type of the B functions’ parameters...

I thought that this is achievable with reflection but is it possible in Swift?

**Edit:1**
Let’s consider three cases for the function B that I want to support:

```
func functionB() {
    print(“HelloWorld”) 
}


func functionB(a: Int) {
     print(“HelloWorld1”)
}

func functionB(a: Int, b:String) -> Int {
     print(“HelloWorld2”)
     return 2
}
```

I want that, independently of the signature method of the function B, to perform different tasks in function A, that has as a parameter the function B.

```
func functionA(function: I don’t know how to pass the different cases of the function B as a parameter...generic types?) {
       if function.args = 0 {
            print(“First example”)
       }
      if function.firstParameter.self is Int.Type {
            print(“second Example”)
      }
      etc...
```

I want to achieve this in order to handle different signature methods with the same function.

**Edit 2:** Sorry for not having specify it before but I don’t have access to function B. I have to figured out during runtime not build time. The two functions are in a separate package.
The objective was that an app had to perform different tasks dynamically at runtime knowing only the method’s signature, specifically the parameter types.

Comment: Swift already has a bunch of metadata for this kind of stuff internally, but doesn't really have reflection APIs that use it. There are third party reflection libraries that do that, which you can check out. However, this set up seems pretty suspect, I suspect there's probably a better way to crack that nut. What're you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such function B? In Swift a function can only have a fixed number of parameters in the general case.

Comment: I’ll edit the question in order to reply to your comments.

Comment: Show us how you're getting `functionB` at runtime.

Comment: This is one problem. I know that in other languages I can pass a function (B) that can have 0,1 or 2 parameters to a  Single function(A) that accepts all of them. Is it possible in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Overload.

```swift
func functionA(functionB: () -> Void) { functionB() }
func functionA(functionB: (Int) -> Void) { functionB(0) }
func functionA(functionB: (Int, String) -> Int) { functionB(0, "") }

functionA(functionB: functionB as () -> Void)
functionA( functionB: functionB(a:) )
functionA( functionB: functionB(a:b:) )
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in a comment you could use `Any`:

```
func functionA(f: Any, a: Int?, b: String?) {
    if let f = f as? () -> Void {
        f()
    } else if let f = f as? (Int) -> Void , let a = a {
        f(a)
    } else if let f = f as? (Int, String) -> Int, let a = a, let b = b {
        let result = f(a, b)
        print(result)
    } else {
        print("f is not a valid object")
    }
}

func functionB(a: Int, b: String) -> Int {
    print(a, b)
    return 3
}

functionA(f: functionB, a: 42, b: "Hello world")
```

Comment: Sorry for not having specify it before but I don’t have access to functionB. I have to figured out during runtime not build time.

Comment: wrapping up functions in classes like this isn't even necessary, you could accept an `Any` and cast like `as? (Int, String) -> Int`